# Is there a way to select a web audio node with a variable in place of the nodes name?

Tags: javascript, html, web-audio-api

I have a bank of 5 oscillator nodes and want to be able to select the waveshape of specific nodes. All oscillators hare names osc1, osc2, osc3 etc. and I want to be able to select which one I'm changing with the elements id (1, 2, 3 etc.)

This is what I thought would work:

```
var oscNum = ("osc"+eleNum)

if (element.value == 1)
{
    oscNum.type = 'square';
}

else if (element.value == 2)
{
oscNum.type = "sawtooth";
}

else if (element.value == 3)
{
oscNum.type = "triangle";
}

else if (element.value == 0)
{
oscNum.type = "sine";           
}
```

However it doesn't and I'm wondering if there's any way it's possible to use `var.type` instead of `osc1.type` to select a node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example the first line of code is computing a string. Let's say that `eleNum` equals 3. Then the value of `oscNum` would be just the string `"osc3"`.

If you want to select your oscillators by their index you can for example use an array to store them.

```
const oscillators = [ osc0, osc1, osc2, osc3 ];
```

Later on you can select an individual oscillator by its index and set the type.

```
oscillators[eleNum].type = "triangle";
```